# Creating an Exception in Python for improper user id on command line

Tags: python

The user needs to enter a path to their file along with an id that is on every line in their file. I have created an exception for a wrong file and I want to do the same if the id that is typed doesn't match what's in the file. How do I do this?

```
import ConfigParser, os
import csv
import sys, getopt
import time
import datetime

from sys import argv
script, solutionId, input_file = argv

def check_all(f):
    print f.read()

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

try:
    current_file = open(input_file)
    check_all(current_file)
except IOError, e:
    print '%s, please try again.' % e
```

Comment: You should ask yourself *why* you want to declare a new exception. Exceptions are for you and programmers using your code as a library. If this is a user-facing interface, you generally want to print error messages, not raise exceptions for the user to see. If you decide you still want exceptions, ask yourself if the built-in exceptions be used. If not, why not?

Comment: Thanks. I will just print an error message.

Comment: Actually I do need an exception. There are other programmers using this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well just declare your exception:

```
class WrongId(Exception): pass
```

And raise it when checking the file integrity:

```
if not check_id_in_file(input_id):
    raise WrongId()
```